# Re-binding the value returned by resolve in javascript promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to pass context along a promise chain.  I thought I could use `function.prototype.bind` since I can see that `Promise.resolve` inherits from `function` but it doesn't work.

In node I get `[TypeError: Promise.resolve.bind(...) is not a function]`
In chrome, for example, I get `VM1043:1 Uncaught TypeError: object is not a constructor(…)`

Is it possible to pass a base object along the promise chain via context?

```
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var o = {};
  o.p1 = 't' + error_or_n('t', '1');
  resolve(o)
})
  .then(o => {
    console.log(o.p1);
    return pp(o.p1, '-> q' + error_or_n('t', '2'))
      .then( function (_) {
        Promise.resolve.bind(o)(o.p1 = _ )
      });
  })
  .then(() => {
    var o = this;
    console.log(o.p1);
    return pp(o.p1, '-> q' + error_or_n('t', '3'))
      .then( function (_) {Promise.resolve.bind(o)(o.p1 = _  + '|')});
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(this.p1);
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

### EDIT

To restate my objective, I want all promises in a chain to have access to a common base object, without resorting to globals.

My idea was to create a promise chain where all resolutions are rebound to said common base object.  It's analogous to `return this` in chainable objects.

The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440548/2670182) explains why I can't use `bind` to do this and suggests using a closure.  The other way I found was to insert an extra `then`, before returning, that carried out some transformation and then returned the base object.  This creates the `return this` style chaining that I imagined.

Both options are here

```
/**
 * Created by cool.blue on 11-Sep-16.
 */
var throw_dont = '0';  // enter 1..3 to throw
var error_or_n = (x, y) => {
  if(throw_dont && y == throw_dont)
    throw(new Error('in ' + x + y));
  else
    return y
};

/**
 *  arbitrary function that returns a promise
 * */
var pp = (o, n) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 0, `${o.p1}-> ${o.n}${error_or_n(o.n, n)}`)
  })
};

/**
 * Method 1 :: +1
 * insert an extra 'then' before returning
 * */
var q = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var o = {n: 'q'};
  o.p1 = 'q' + error_or_n('q', '1');
  resolve(o)
})
  .then(o => {
    console.log(o.p1);
    return pp(o, 2).then(_ => {
        o.p1 = _;
        return o
      });
  })
  .then((o) => {
    console.log(o.p1);
    return pp(o, 3).then(_ => {
        o.p1 = _ + '|';
        return o
      });
  })
  .then(o => {
    console.log(o.p1);
    return Promise.resolve(o)
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

/**
 * Method 2 :: +1
 * use closures
 *
 * */
var t = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var o = {n: 't'};
  o.p1 = 't' + error_or_n('t', '1');
  resolve(o)
})
  .then(o => {
    console.log(o.p1);
    return pp(o, 2)
      .then(_ => {
        o.p1 = _;
        console.log(o.p1);
        return pp(o, 3)
      })
      .then(_ => {
        o.p1 = _ + "|";
        console.log(o.p1);
        return Promise.resolve(o)
      })
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));


Promise.all([q, t]).then(_ => {
  if(_.every(_ => _)) {
    console.log('all done...');
    console.dir(_)
  }
});
Promise.race([q, t]).then(_ => {
  if(_) {
    console.log('1\'st done...');
    console.dir(_)
  }
});
```

Comment: I think, the first param for bind function shd be 'null'.  So, should it be
Promise.resolve.bind(null, 0)(...) ?

Comment: The first argument is the object I want to bind, setting it to null means nothing is bound.

Comment: the first arg u wanna bind shd be the 2nd arg to bind fn. bind takes a context object as first arg. Your actual param then comes next

Comment: The context is what I want to bind. Setting the first argument to null is the opposite of what I want to do. As explained in the question I'm trying to pass context.

Comment: `pp`, `error_of_n`? Unable to reproduce the error with your example code.

Comment: you can't use bind here, and if it was possible "call" is more appropriate, you can't because you bind Promise.resolve but the function that is execute with the then is not Promise.resolve so it is not the same function and bind don't work. you need to use a closuse juste declare your variable to a upper level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing isn't possible. You can't influence the `this` context of a `then` handler by doing some manipulation in an earlier `then`. The `this` value of a `then` handler is determined entirely by the function itself (global object/undefined by default, or some value if the function itself is bound ahead of time).

This is declared in the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-35):

> `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` must be called as functions (i.e. with no `this` value). [[3.2](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-69)]

If you want to have `o` easily accessible across multiple `then`s, you can employ nesting:

```
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var o = {};
  o.p1 = 't' + error_or_n('t', '1');
  resolve(o)
})
.then(o => {
   console.log(o.p1);

   return pp(o.p1, '-> q' + error_or_n('t', '2'))
     .then( function (_) {
        o.p1 = _;
     })
     .then( function () {
        // do something else with o
     })
     .then( function () {
        // do more with o
     });
})
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the very definitive answer. I figured out a second way as well that is analogous to `return this`, I can just rebind a base object with an extra `then`.